Cannot Delete Registry Keys
I am trying to delete the registry keys provided in the attachment below in order to change the order of other context menu values but regedit prevents me from doing it.

What I have tried:

Running regedit as SYSTEM
Setting the ownership of everything to my user
Safe boot with basically no drivers running

I'd appreciate any answers given.

https://superuser.com/search?q=error+while+deleting+key

Hello @spikey_richie, none of the solutions provided in those posts work, which is why I made this one. This is my last, not first resort.

These keys are protected, even from administrators and SYSTEM.
Only the highly protected TrustedInstaller account has a full-control
permission for these keys.
There is a reason for Microsoft to have done it, so in modifying these
(not really bad) keys you take a big risk of making Windows unusable.
To answer the question, Nirsoft's
AdvancedRun
can run a program such as regedit under the TrustedInstaller account.
I strongly recommend not modifying these keys. If you decide to do so,
take a backup of these keys and create a System Restore point,
so you could boot into Safe mode and rollback Windows to its current
state.

I just solved my main issue, which was moving around the open with context items.
I am very thankful you shared this tool though. I'll use it!
